# Calling a JSON API with Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http

I am trying to get the facebook profile picture of the user logged into my application. Facebook's API states that `http://graph.facebook.com/517267866/?fields=picture` returns the correct URL as a JSON object.

I want to get the URL to the picture out of my code. I tried the following but I am missing something here.

```
 var url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/517267866/?fields=picture';

 http.get(url, function(res) {
      var fbResponse = JSON.parse(res)
      console.log("Got response: " + fbResponse.picture);
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
 });
```

Running this code results in the following:

```
undefined:1

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The `res` argument in the `http.get()` callback is not the body, but rather an [http.ClientResponse](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_clientresponse) object. You need to assemble the body:

```
var url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/517267866/?fields=picture';

http.get(url, function(res){
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        var fbResponse = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Got a response: ", fbResponse.picture);
    });
}).on('error', function(e){
      console.log("Got an error: ", e);
});
```

Comment: The res argument is actually an [http.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) object now.  From what I can gather, the ClientResponse class has been refactored out of node's http library.

Comment: request module will take care of simple http get/post/etc.. for you https://github.com/request/request

Comment: Wow, that's lower-level than I'd expect from a standard library in this day-and-age.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` throws exceptions on invalid JSON and should always be called inside a `try/catch` block or otherwise the entire program can crash on invalid data (which sometimes happen).

Comment: To avoid having to do a `try/catch` for `JSON.parse` (which should **always** be done if you use `JSON.parse` - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29798770/613198)) you can use a module like `request` that can parse JSON automatically for you, as I showed in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826384/calling-a-json-api-with-node-js/39612292#39612292) below.

Answer (score 57):

### Problems with other answers:

- unsafe `JSON.parse`
- no response code checking

All of the answers here use `JSON.parse()` in an **unsafe way**.
You should always put all calls to `JSON.parse()` in a `try/catch` block **especially** when you parse JSON coming from an external source, like you do here.

You can use `request` to parse the JSON automatically which wasn't mentioned here in other answers. There is already an answer using `request` module but it uses `JSON.parse()` to manually parse JSON - which should **always** be run inside a `try {} catch {}` block to handle errors of incorrect JSON or otherwise the entire app will crash. And incorrect JSON happens, trust me.

Other answers that use `http` also use `JSON.parse()` without checking for exceptions that can happen and crash your application.

Below I'll show few ways to handle it safely.

All examples use a public GitHub API so everyone can try that code safely.

### Example with `request`

Here's a working example with `request` that automatically parses JSON:

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');

var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/rsp';

request.get({
    url: url,
    json: true,
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
  }, (err, res, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error:', err);
    } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
      console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
    } else {
      // data is already parsed as JSON:
      console.log(data.html_url);
    }
});
```

### Example with `http` and `try/catch`

This uses `https` - just change `https` to `http` if you want HTTP connections:

```
'use strict';
var https = require('https');

var options = {
    host: 'api.github.com',
    path: '/users/rsp',
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
};

https.get(options, function (res) {
    var json = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        json += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            try {
                var data = JSON.parse(json);
                // data is available here:
                console.log(data.html_url);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('Error parsing JSON!');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        }
    });
}).on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error:', err);
});
```

### Example with `http` and `tryjson`

This example is similar to the above but uses the [`tryjson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryjson) module. (Disclaimer: I am the author of that module.)

```
'use strict';
var https = require('https');
var tryjson = require('tryjson');

var options = {
    host: 'api.github.com',
    path: '/users/rsp',
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
};

https.get(options, function (res) {
    var json = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        json += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            var data = tryjson.parse(json);
            console.log(data ? data.html_url : 'Error parsing JSON!');
        } else {
            console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
        }
    });
}).on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error:', err);
});
```

### Summary

The example that uses `request` is the simplest. But if for some reason you don't want to use it then remember to always check the response code and to parse JSON safely.

Comment: How can I export data and use it somewhere else? All the answers just use console log and not mention how to use it somewhere else?

Answer (score 19):

I think that for simple HTTP requests like this it's better to use the [`request` module](https://github.com/request/request). You need to install it with npm (`npm install request`) and then your code can look like this:

```
const request = require('request')
     ,url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/517267866/?fields=picture'

request(url, (error, response, body)=> {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    const fbResponse = JSON.parse(body)
    console.log("Got a response: ", fbResponse.picture)
  } else {
    console.log("Got an error: ", error, ", status code: ", response.statusCode)
  }
})
```

Comment: 2021 still works

Answer (score 13):

I'm using [get-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-json) very simple to use:

```
$ npm install get-json --save
```

Import `get-json`

```
var getJSON = require('get-json')
```

To do a `GET` request you would do something like:

```
getJSON('http://api.listenparadise.org', function(error, response){
    console.log(response);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to user [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios):

```
npm install axios
```

Code will be like:

```
const url = `${this.env.someMicroservice.address}/v1/my-end-point`;

const { data } = await axios.get<MyInterface>(url, {
  auth: {
    username: this.env.auth.user,
    password: this.env.auth.pass
  }
});

return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Unirest library](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-nodejs) simplifies this a lot. If you want to use it, you have to install `unirest` npm package. Then your code could look like this:

```
unirest.get("http://graph.facebook.com/517267866/?fields=picture")
  .send()
  .end(response=> {
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("Got a response: ", response.body.picture)
    } else {
      console.log("Got an error: ", response.error)
    }
  })
```