# Why is this data parsing failing?

Tags: json, node.js, http, https

I'm writing a Node.js server and I'm trying to fetch data from an API and return it to my user. I'm taking the `insightlyResponse` and trying to convert to JSON. Here's my code:

```
  insightlyResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
      let rawData = '';
    insightlyResponse.on('data', (chunk) => rawData += chunk);
    insightlyResponse.on('end', () => {
    try {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
        responseData = "PARSED";
    } catch (e) {
        responseData = `Got error: ${e.message}`
    }
  response.end(responseData);
  });
```

The error is `Got error: Unexpected token \u001f in JSON at position 0`. What does this mean and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "trying to convert to JSON" I think you mean "trying to convert _from_ JSON". What's in `rawData`? Presumably not JSON.

Comment: @smarx I'm following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826384/calling-a-json-api-with-node-js

Comment: If I don't parse and leave as is I get a bunch of gibberish, if I do parse I get an error.

Comment: Why did you think that trying to parse "a bunch of gibberish" as though it were JSON would work?

Comment: Step 1 will be figuring out what sort of data you actually have. (This probably involves reading documentation for the API you're calling or whatever `insightlyResponse` is.) Then figure out if you need to do something different to get JSON or if you need to learn how to parse the response you're already getting.

Comment: @smarx This API documentation says it returns JSON. I ran AJAX off my browser and the API worked just fine, until they disabled CORS.

Comment: I doubt others are going to be able to help you without knowing what API you're using, seeing how you're calling it, what type of thing `insightlyResponse` is, etc. So either you'll need to provide more information, or you'll need to do some debugging yourself (e.g. try calling a different API to make sure that part of your code works correctly, or try to identify what the "gibberish" actually is).

Comment: @smarx The API is here if you'd like to see it: https://api.insight.ly/v2.2/Help#!/Contacts/GetContacts

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I double-checked the API and realized that it can return compressed responses. Turned off that setting and works like a charm!