# Getting the top card from a Trello list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, trello

I am trying to get the top card from a list using Javascript.
I saw another post on this but the code was outdated / no longer working.

I have a Trello list, called "Flights" and I would appreciate if someone could help me with this. Simply, I want to get the top card in a Trello list, along with the **custom fields** of the card.

So far, I have tried the following code:

```js
 // Getting all lists from a certain board.
        fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/boards/0Ph2WHXQ/lists?key=5fe33d73bded56ada14decf701da0203&token=e353cb19fabc8dfbea36e1b824a92ff0b358860b1de2d11c745f6e8321edfc09`, {
            method: 'GET',
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let lists = JSON.parse(response.body);
            // Searching for a list with a certain name and store it's id.
            let certainListId = lists.find(list => list.name === "Flights").id;

            // Use the stored id in certainListId to get all cards of the list.
            fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/lists/${certainListId}/cards`, {
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(response => {

                let certainListCards = JSON.parse(response.body);
                // Cards in the array is in top to bottom order. So top one is the very first.
                let firstCard = certainListCards[0];

                console.log(firstCard)

                // Send with the bot the name of the first (top) card thanks to firstCard.name property.

            }).catch(err => console.error(err));

        }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

However, I get the following error message:
[image]

The error is on the line:

```js
let lists = JSON.parse(response.body);
```

I have tried the code without the JSON.parse, but I have an error "Typeerror: lists.find is not a function"

I assume I need the parse code, but I have zero idea why it's not working. I have attached an image of just printing the response.body to the console.

Image:
[image]

Thank you for reading this, and I would highly appreciate some help. I am using node.js (latest version), using the cross-fetch module for the 'fetch' command. I am just requiring it as

```js
const fetch = require("cross-fetch");
```

I highly doubt that would cause any issues, but feel free to enlighten me.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the cross-fetch docs, you don't get the data from `response.body`, instead it's passed into the second promise.

This works, lists returns an array of objects:

```
let fetch = require('cross-fetch');

fetch('https://api.trello.com/1/boards/0Ph2WHXQ/lists?key=5fe33d73bded56ada14decf701da0203&token=e353cb19fabc8dfbea36e1b824a92ff0b358860b1de2d11c745f6e8321edfc09')
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error("Bad response from server");
    }
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(lists => {
    console.log(lists);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    id: '5d2364f2c87d3d4913fe2061',
    name: 'READ ME & TEMPLATE',
    closed: false,
    idBoard: '5d2363b2748e8e88009875f0',
    pos: 65535,
    subscribed: false,
    softLimit: null
  },....
```

---

Alternatively, while this doesn't answer your question, here's a solution to your code that just uses the NodeJS api:

```
const https = require('https')

// this should be in a .gitignored an environment file
key = "5fe33d73bded56ada14decf701da0203&token=e353cb19fabc8dfbea36e1b824a92ff0b358860b1de2d11c745f6e8321edfc09"

function getBoardLists(boardsId, callback) {

    const options = {
        hostname: 'api.trello.com',
        port: 443,
        path: `/1/boards/${boardsId}/lists?key=${key}`,
        method: 'GET'
    }

    https.request(options, res => {
        // references https://stackoverflow.com/a/39612292/9824103
        var json = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            json += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                try {
                    var lists = JSON.parse(json);

                    callback(lists, null)

                } catch (e) {
                    callback(null, error)
                }
            } else {
                callback(null, Error(`Status code ${res.statusCode} is not 200`))
            }
        });

    }).on('error', error => {
        callback(null, error)
    }).end()
}
function getList(listId, callback) {

    const options = {
        hostname: 'api.trello.com',
        port: 443,
        path: `/1/lists/${listId}/cards?key=${key}`,
        method: 'GET'
    }

    https.request(options, res => {
        // references https://stackoverflow.com/a/39612292/9824103
        var json = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            json += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                try {
                    var lists = JSON.parse(json);

                    callback(lists, null)

                } catch (e) {
                    callback(null, error)
                }
            } else {
                callback(null, Error(`Status code ${res.statusCode} is not 200`))
            }
        });

    }).on('error', error => {
        callback(null, error)
    }).end()
}

getBoardLists("0Ph2WHXQ", (lists, error) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.error(error)
    }

    console.log(lists)

    let flightsListId = lists.find(list => list.name === "Flights").id;

    getList(flightsListId, (list, error) => {

        if (error) {
            return console.error(error)
        }

        console.log(list)
    })
})
```